# Azure Blob Storage Download Failing

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download a simple XML file that I have in Azure Blob Storage for my WP8.1 Silverlight App. It doesn't work on my old beat-up Lumia 520 though. It works on every other phone and emulator I've tried though. Here's the line of code where it fails:

```
myXmlDoc.LoadXml(await myBlobStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("tileinfo").GetBlockBlobReference("test.xml").DownloadTextAsync());
```

And here are the errors:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Windows.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Windows.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.ni.DLL
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.ni.DLL
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.ni.DLL
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Anyone know what is going on here? The Phone is running 8.10.12400.899.

Comment: can you show what kind of exception is throw?